# Why Firebase Function calling Firebase admin.messaging.sendToDevice() cannot create notification on Android device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, android-notifications

I have an Android app, and am trying to send a notification to a specific device on which it is installed, using the Firebase Messaging API from a Firebase Function. But the notification never shows up. However, sending manually from the Firebase Console does make a notification show up successfully on the same device. Here is the relevant Firebase Function code:

```
        var message = {
        notification: {
            title: notifTitle,
            body: notifBody,
            sound: 'default',
            android_channel_id: 'update_channel',
            channel_id: 'update_channel'
            // tag:
        }
    };
    var options = {}
    console.log(message);
    console.log('registrationToken: ' + registrationToken);

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice([registrationToken], message, options)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
    ...
```

Which logs the following when invoked, appearing to have sent the notification successfully:

```
{ results: [ { messageId: '0:1544572985549904%5be491645be49164' } ],
canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
failureCount: 0,
successCount: 1,
multicastId: 5825519571250606000 }
```

In my Android app I've created the update_channel in the main activity's onCreate() (because, from what I've gathered, Android Oreo API 26+ requires a specific channel...):

```
    private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String id = getString(R.string.update_notification_channel);
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.app_name);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
        channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        //channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

And also setting it as the default channel in the Manifest:

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="update_notification_channel"/>
```

I don't know if the problem is channel-related, or if I'm missing a step somewhere, or what.

Answer (score 0):

For notifications to work while the app is in the foreground or background, you must implement and register a FirebaseMessagingService in your Android app, to receive calls on onMessageReceived(), then create notifications with the NotificationManager in there manually when a notification message comes in.

From [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive):

> Firebase notifications behave differently depending on the foreground/background state of the receiving app. If you want foregrounded apps to receive notification messages or data messages, you’ll need to write code to handle the onMessageReceived callback.